# Dyads for multiple variables

Tags: stata

I am trying to create dyads in my Stata data set for multiple variables, at the same time.

Here is what I have:

```
Year id Freedom
2005 1  6.8
2006 1  7.0
.
.
2016 1  5.5
2005 2  3.8
2006 2  4.2
.
.
.
2016 2  5.4
```

I would like to turn it into this

```
Year id_origin id_dest Freedom_orig Freedom_dest
2005   1         2         6.8           3.8 
2006   1         2         7.0           4.2
.
.
.
2016   2         1         5.4           5.5
```

Comment: So, is that it? Namely you have 1 and 2 and no others?

Comment: Hi Nick, this was just a small sample. In the original dataset, the id are the 50 states of the US, for years 2005-2016. So, it's 1, 2, 3,.....,50. Therefore, doing it manually does not seem ideal.

Comment: where does `_orig` and `_dest` come from? There is only one variable `Freedom` in the dataset.

Comment: Correct, there is only one Freedom and one ID because I need to create dyads, for both variables, at the same time. _orig and _dest come from the creation of dyads in both variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a hard time understand what you needed. Maybe as I was not familiar with what dyads are.

My understanding is that in the first data set you have year-id observations. And in the result dataset you have year-id1-id2 observations where id1-id2 represents all possible id pairs from the first dataset. If that is correct, then you can use this code:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input double(year id freedom)
2005 1 6.8
2006 1   7
2016 1 5.5
2005 2 3.8
2006 2 4.2
2016 2 5.4
2005 3 3.1
2006 3 3.2
2016 3 3.3
end

* Save original data to be merged as dest data
preserve
    tempfile destdata
    rename id id_dest
    rename freedom freedom_dest
    save `destdata'
restore    
 
* rename the orig variables
rename id id_orig
rename freedom freedom_orig

* count number of ids in data set. For each year-id add one row per id in the dataset
levelsof id_orig
expand `r(r)'

* Within each year-id, gen id_dest 1, 2 ... to the number if ids
bysort id_orig year : gen id_dest = _n

* Drop rows where both ids are the same
drop if id_orig == id_dest

* Merge the data from id_dest
merge m:1 year id_dest using `destdata', nogen

* Sort and order data
sort id_orig year id_dest
order year id_orig id_dest freedom_orig freedom_dest
```

This code assumes that the id is indeed `1`, `2`, `3` ... `n`, skipping no values. You will have to create this id if the id in your actual data is `A`, `B`, `C` etc. or something like that.

Comment: In the first dataset, I have year-id-freedom observation; in the result dataset, I have year-id1-id2-freedom1-freedom2 (with 1 & 2 being called orig & dest) where id1-id2 and freedom1-freedom2 represents all possible id pairs from the first dataset. Ideally, I need to create pairs for both id and freedom, simultaneously.

Comment: now I am lost again. I think that is what my code does. Did you try to run it? Can you explain what in the results are not as you expected?

Comment: first of all, thank you very much for your help. I was just trying to explain a bit better what I am trying to do. I tried to run the code and I only encountered 2 small issues: 1) exp `r(r)' doesn't work, so I used exp id_orig. 2) there are some missing values resulting from the merge. I substituted m:1 with m:m but was not able to remove all missing values (there should not be any, I think). Thanks again!

Comment: 1) `expand id_orig` will create missing values in the merge as it adds one row for id=1, 2 rows for id=2 etc. when all rows should expanded into exactly 50 rows. This is probably the explanation to 2). What version of the Stata are you using? My code should not give errors and result in no missing values if you copy it exactly as is.

Comment: I have stata 14. When I use expand `r(r)', what I see is: =exp required
r(100); that's why I tried to use expand id_orig. Could that be due to the fact I am using an old version of the software ?

Comment: Just solved it, using expand 50 :)

Comment: You must use `levelsof id_orig` immediately before ``expand `r(r)'`` for it to work, but hardcoding to 50 should also work. Consider upvoting and accept the answer if it was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks a lot, again! I accepted the answer and voted. Unfortunately, my reputation is not high enough to cast a vote, but my feedback has been recorded.